# Can Unicode compression in SQL 2008 R2 cause GUIDs to become corrupt?

Tags: database, guid, collation, sql-server-2008-r2

We recently had some trouble with our production SQL 2008 R2 databases and had to failover to log-shipped warm spares for most of our databases. This morning I found some very odd GUID values scattered throughout our set of databases. For background, we have a main clients database, that holds various information about installed clients, including the master client_guid that is referenced in other tables and other databases. I am seeing that the GUIDs in some of the support dbs have become corrupted with Kanji and Cyrillic characters. For example: In our main client data table, a particular record had a GUID of '4d86854e-d699-4bce-a98b-c34fcc909453', but in the Analytics database that same GUID is showing up as '4d86854e-d699-4bce瞧ＲĹ（Ɏ-c34fcc909453'.

I have been wracking my brain today trying to figure out how this might have happened. I stumbled upon some information about Unicode compression, and I was wondering if it might be possible for SQL Server to mangle these GUIDs during a database restore.

Collation throughout our db system is set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

I'm wondering if anyone has any insight into this problem.

Comment: "We recently had some trouble with our production SQL 2008 R2 databases" - what sort of trouble?  Disk failures?

Comment: There are a few different things going on at the moment. First, we recently tried to migrate our dbs to a new SAN system. We know the SAN was not configured optimally, but there were no disk failures as far as we can tell. The prod db server was experiencing very erratic performance with cpu thrashing. We failed our production dbs over to our backup servers because our web site and applications had become unresponsive.

Comment: As of this morning, I see that more records in our Analytics database have become "corrupt".

Comment: What datatype are you storing these `GUID` s as? If `uniqueidentifier` collation and Unicode should be completely irrelevant.